# Radiation in an ideal LC circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits

In ceveral textbooks it is said that an ideal LC circuit does not lose its energy, it just bounces from the capacitor to the inductor coil back and forth.

On the other hand, any system where charges are going to be accelerated
radiate energy (that's should *always* happen when involved charges are going to be proper accelerated, which is a consequence
of Maxwell equations). But then due to this, even an ideal LC circuit should lose after any cycle a certain amount of its energy as radiation, since the charges there are accelerated at all?

Therefore I'm confused at that point: Does Bremsstrahlung not occur in an ideal LC circuit (why? That does not make any sense, the charges there are going to be accelerated, so this should give by Maxwell theory radiation losses)? But if this accelerations of charges takes place there, then the energy loss cannot be ignored even in this ideal case, or can it?

Does anybody see how to resolve my confusion?

Comment: A situation of the same type (radiation from a circuit with two capacitors and without resistance) was studied in the american journal of physics : https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/70/4/415/1042363/The-two-capacitor-problem-with-radiation

Comment: Well, it will try to radiate as an antenna, and an awfully poor one at that given the likely size of your circuit relative to the wavelength in the kilo to MegaHertz. Now, why you think Bremsstrahlung is the most likely radiation path is another question...

Comment: @JonCuster: because so far I know it classically (by "classically" I mean based on usual undergrade EM Maxwell theory) the Bremsstrahlung is the only kind explanating  energy loss of EM systems involving moved charges. So I thought that an idealized system (like an ideal LC circuit in this case) should behave compatibly wrt everything which comes from classical Maxwell theory

Comment: To which kind of another radiation effects are you refering to?

Comment: Classical Maxwell equations can just have charge sloshing back and forth, radiating. You don't need large accelerations around nuclei. You don't treat FM radio waves as the product of Bremsstrahlung.

Comment: @user267839 We normally reserve "bremsstrahlung" to refer to radiation due to impulsive acceleration of individual electrons. Oscillating currents (which need not be due to electrons) also radiate, of course.

Comment: Ok sorry, posting this question I used the term "Bremsstrahlung" unfortunately synomously for all radiation efectly comming from accelerating charges. If that's not standard, I will revise my formulation

Comment: replace everywhere where I wrote "Bremsstrahlung" by simply "accelerations of charges" in any way it may happen in a reasonable model

Comment: @user267839 Why not do the physics? Build an LC circuit and see how it works. Textbook idealizations are not real physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There is indeed loss of energy in an LC circuit due to exactly the process you mentioned. However, I would say this loss of energy tends to be negligible in most common situations, so it is often ignored.

Let me further explain. Indeed, acceleration leads to radiation. However, remember the drift velocities of electrons in a wire tend to be really small, and hence so are their accelerations. We do not expect the accelerations to be too relevant to the point of actually generating strong fields. The radiative corrections are likely to be very small in comparison with the fields due to the currents and other effects in the circuit.

In addition to these effects being small, there is also the matter that taking radiation into account is not particularly easy and it could considerably complicate the description of these processes. The following is just a crude guess, but I believe the energy loss due to the small resistance in real wires could be more relevant than the radiation loss. Estimating the orders of magnitude of both these effects could be an interesting exercise.